# How to compare multidimensional array keys

Tags: php, arrays

What I'm trying to do is compare the keys of the second level of a multidimensional array. here's an example:

```
$data = array(
     array(
          $a => $b,
          $c => $d
     ),
     array(
          $e => $f,
          $g => $h
     )
)
```

How would I compare $a & $e?

Comment: compare these arrays => array_keys($data[0]),array_keys($data[1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, knowing that they have the same size and you want to compare sorted keys:

```
<?php

$data_1 = array_keys($data[0]);
$data_2 = array_keys($data[1]);

$size = count($data_1);
for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++)
{
    if($data_1[$i]<$data_2[$i])
    {//do smth
    }

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys0 = array_keys($data[0]);
$keys1 = array_keys($data[1]);

if ($keys0[0] == $keys1[0])
{
    ...
}
```